# How to use OpenCover for XUnit Test Coverage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, opencover, reportgenerator

I would like to integrate OpenCover for XUnit test coverage to my Visual Studio project. I made a little example project just for testing the integration.

My example solution **OpenCoverProject** has two projects.

One XUnit project **UnitTests** with a **ProgramUT.cs** file:

```
public class ProgramUT
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(0, 0, 0)]
    [InlineData(12, 10, 2)]
    [InlineData(-6, -2, -4)]
    public void AddTest(int _expected, int _x, int _y)
    {
        int actual = MyMathClass.Add(_x, _y);
        Assert.Equal(_expected, actual);
    }
}
```

And the main project **Learning** with a **Program.cs** file:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}

public class MyMathClass
{
    public static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

I also have a script file which executes OpenCover and ReportGenerator. **00** is just a placeholder for some more path string.

```
set OpenCoverConsolePath=C:\Users\00\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe
set XUnitConsolePath=C:\Users\00\packages\xunit.runner.console\2.4.1\tools\net461\xunit.console.exe
set LearningExePath=C:\Users\00\OpenCoverProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Learning.exe 
set ReportGeneratorPath=C:\Users\00\ReportGenerator\netcoreapp3.0\ReportGenerator.exe

"%OpenCoverConsolePath%" ^
-target:"%XUnitConsolePath%" ^
-targetargs:"%LearningExePath%" ^
-output:"CodeCoverageResult.xml" ^
-register:user 

"%ReportGeneratorPath%" ^
-reports:"CodeCoverageResult.xml" ^
-targetdir:"Report" ^
-sourcedirs:"Report"

start Report\index.htm

pause
```

When I execute the script file I get following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown test framework: could not find xunit.dll (v1) or xunit.execution.*.dll (v2) in C:\Users\00\OpenCoverProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1

I expect OpenCover to analyze that every method (it's just **Add** in our case) gets tested by the xunit tests.
I don't know how I can manage this. I suppose the target should be **xunit.console.exe** and has to link to my Learning project **Learning.exe** somehow by the targetargs.

It would be great if someone has a hint or a solution for this problem.

Comment: It seems that you will need to set xunit first and only THEN opencover...

Comment: How can I set xunit in the script?